# Jquery .hide() and .show() are slowing down on firefox but work great on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a tree with child elements and for hide and show them on user click, I use the .show('fast') and .hide('fast') jquery functions.
But I noticed that on firefox the transition between the two state are slowing down but on Chrome it works like a charm.

I have the latest version of firefox.

You should also know that I use different libraries into my website such as bootstrap , datatable.js . I tell you because I see that the slowdown is less pronounced on codepen.io that on my site.

[this is the codepen.io with my tree](http://codepen.io/robert91/pen/VaXQbx)

And that's my javascript code :

```
$('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function(e) {
    var child = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
    if (child.is(":visible")) {
        child.hide('fast');
        $(this).find('>i').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    } else {
        child.show('fast');
        $(this).find('>i').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Javascript and jQuery is client side progaramin, and that means that it is the clients hardware that determents how fast the code is processed. I can not see any difference in speed om my computer.

Comment: @Zorken17 Thanks for your comment, you mean that my graphic board is the origin of the problem ?

Comment: @KhoyaDev If you are so much concerned, you may use the CSS transitions. Would you like a solution on that?

Comment: I mean that all client side code depends om the users hardware. So yes, if the user has hardware that is not powerful to run multipel things the result can show upp as slow animations i different browsers depending on how demanding the browser is.

Comment: Yes, agreed with @Zorken17 too...

Comment: @Zorken17 I don't know if that's my hardware because I have a nvidia GeForce GT620M, I know It's not the most powerful graphic boards but it's not the less powerful graphic boards too...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes a css solution should be great thank you

Comment: @KhoyaDev You really have a better board than most of them. So don't worry. Lemme post you a CSS version.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thank you a lot, but that's why I want to know what's wrong lol

Comment: @KhoyaDev Kindly check your task manager and see if everything is under control... Some crazy flash?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109134/discussion-between-khoyadev-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

This was my attempt:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function(e) {
    var parent = $(this).closest('li.parent_li');
    parent.toggleClass("open");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.administrationRowTab {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.tab-pane,
.active {
  color: inherit;
}


/*TREE STYLE*/

.tree ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.tree .parent_li > span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tree i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.parent_li .glyphicon-chevron-down,
.parent_li.open .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  display: none;
}

.parent_li.open .glyphicon-chevron-down {
  display: inline-block;
}

.parent_li ul {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}

.parent_li.open ul {
  height: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row m-t-25">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row administrationRowTab">
      <ul id="tabUl" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tabBuildConfiguration" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Test</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active m-t-25" id="tabBuildsConfiguration" style="padding:15px;">
          <div class="row pad-10">
            <div class="tree">
              <ul>
                <li class="parent_li">
                  <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Parent 1</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 1</li>
                    <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 2</li>
                    <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 3</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="parent_li">
                  <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Parent 2</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 1</li>
                    <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 2</li>
                    <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 3</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is pure CSS.**

I added two classes: .chiled-hide and .chiled-show to the css, and updated your js script:

Here is a link to [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/greepO)

```js
$(function(){
        $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function(e){
            var test = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').hasClass('chiled-hide');
            if(test)
            {
                $(this).parent('li.parent_li').removeClass('chiled-hide').addClass('chiled-show');
                $(this).find('>i').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).parent('li.parent_li').removeClass('chiled-show').addClass('chiled-hide');
                $(this).find('>i').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
```

```css
.administrationRowTab{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.tab-pane, .active{
    color : inherit;
}


/*TREE STYLE*/
.tree ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.tree .parent_li > span { cursor: pointer;}

.tree i {margin-right: 5px;}

.chiled-hide > ul {
  display:none;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.chiled-show > ul {
  display:block;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="row m-t-25">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row administrationRowTab">
                <ul id="tabUl" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tabBuildConfiguration" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active m-t-25" id="tabBuildsConfiguration" style="padding:15px;">
                        <div class="row pad-10">
                            <div class="tree">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="parent_li">
                                        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>Parent 1</span>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 1</li>
                                            <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 2</li>
                                            <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 3</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="parent_li">
                                        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>Parent 2</span>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 1</li>
                                            <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 2</li>
                                            <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>Child 3</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oh nice... That's the same attempt even I did... :D Yours doesn't animate though.

Comment: The animation is easy to add as well, but I thought he wanted a fast response on the tree view.

Comment: thank you for both of you, can you just copy and past my codepen.io html tree please because I'm new in my company and I forgot that the company doesn't like I put some element of their website on the net please ^^? Thank you

Comment: @KhoyaDev So you whant me do delete the code from here and just make a link to codepen.io?